# R data output-Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

```
date        day D1  D2 D4   D5W1 D7W2
01-01-2014      1   1   0   0   0   0
02-01-2014      2   0   1   0   0   0
03-01-2014      3   0   0   0   0   0
04-01-2014      4   0   0   1   0   0
05-01-2014     5    0   0   0   1   0
06-01-2014     6    0   0   0   0   0
07-01-2014      7   0   0   0   0   0
08-01-2014     8    0   0   0   0   0
```

I have a dataset till current date along with several dummy variables wherein I am doing forecasting.
I have a regression output where I am getting the weights for all the dummy variables which are

```
D1      D2      D4     D5W1     D7W2
0.03    0.04    0.02    0.01    -0.05
```

The desired output is to generate a factor which will be generated by the multiplying weights from the regression output with the dummy variables corresponding to each date.

```
date                             factor
01-01-2014  
02-01-2014  
03-01-2014  
04-01-2014  
05-01-2014  
06-01-2014
```

Comment: you can get it by `fitted` value which you have it in result.

Answer (score 0):

Also a solution can be using sqldf package if data is in a data frame which is named `df`:

```
library(sqldf)
result <- sqldf("SELECT date, 0.03 * D1 + 0.04 * D2 + 0.02 * D4 + 0.01 * D5W1 - 0.05 * D7W2 as factor
                 FROM df")
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the result.Converted both the dataset into the long format from the wide format.Merged the long dataset using the variable as the key and then multiplied the two columns and converted it back into the wide format.using value.var the output of the product using dcast function.